# Leading zeros are missing when inserting data into sql server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am working on project where i am inserting `productid` into one of table.But here is something strange. If `productid` is like(002374) then in table its saving like(2374),missing leading zeros.

I have checked variable fetching correct `productid(002374)`. Datatype of column is `nvarchar(255)`. And `productid` variable is of string type.

It looks something wrong with datatype or different thing.

Here is my code:

```
productid = dt.Rows(i)(3)
item = dt.Rows(i)(0)
amount = dt.Rows(i)(1)
qty = dt.Rows(i)(2)
Custid = Session("customerid")
Total = Session("price")

Notes = Session("Notes")

Dim con1 As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
con1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnStringDb1").ConnectionString
Dim strConnString1 As String = ""

strConnString1 &= "INSERT INTO Weborder_Details   (OrderID,Qty,Cost,UnitPrice,ProductID,ItemDescription)  VALUES  ('" & result2 & "','" & qty & "', " & amount & "," & amount & "," & productid & ",'" & item & "'); "

Dim cmd2 As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strConnString1, con1)
con1.Open()

cmd.Connection = con1
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Please tell me what i need to solve this issue.

Comment: if product is nvarchar, then why are you not passing it in single quotes? "," & productid & ",'" should be ",'" & productid & "','"

Comment: Iv'e removed the C# tag as it didn't seem relevant. Read up on how to [parameterize your queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection) - this way you don't need to remember to mangle and escape strings.

Comment: ...or even better, a stored procedure

Comment: _Terrible_ naming convention btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that you use [parameterized quer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)y here. You can read the reasoning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509169/parameterized-queries-vs-sql-injection). However, for your problem You are passing productid as integer to database, change this

```
strConnString1 &= "INSERT INTO Weborder_Details   (OrderID,Qty,Cost,UnitPrice,ProductID,ItemDescription)  VALUES  ('" & result2 & "','" & qty & "', " & amount & "," & amount & "," & productid & ",'" & item & "'); "
```

to

```
//note the single quotes around product id
strConnString1 &= "INSERT INTO Weborder_Details   (OrderID,Qty,Cost,UnitPrice,ProductID,ItemDescription)  VALUES  ('" & result2 & "','" & qty & "', " & amount & "," & amount & ",'" & productid & "','" & item & "'); "
```

Comment: this is not a good advice - parameterized queries should be used instead.

Comment: @Knaģis agreed to what you have said, though i haven't advised him to write that code. I was updating my answer when you commented.

Comment: @Ehsan thanks for your suggestion  single quotes does the trick...its something wrong to use this???

Comment: @sikha yes it is. See the links in my answer of the alternative that should be used. And accept it if it was helpful.