# Searching using like

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

When I'm searching my datagrid, it should be always the first word to type. If i type the next word or consecutive letter it contains, it doesn't show.

Example:
I'm going to search Welcome Back. If i type "Elcome" or "back", it doesn't show.

Here is my code...

```
OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From books where Author like ('" + textBox1.Text + "%')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are telling the database to select rows that starts with `textBox1.Text` followed by anything else (`%`) you should change it to

```
"Select * From books where Author like ('%" + textBox1.Text + "%')";
```

this will find all books that their authors have `textBox1.Text` somewhere in their value.

In [like command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) `%` can be replaced by zero or more character.

Also try using [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509169/parameterized-queries-vs-sql-injection), your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).