# Change bootsrap navbar text with asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

My idea is when the user logs in the "login" and "register" will no longer be seen and instead it will show the user name first name on the navbar.

Markup:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Register<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"</span></a>
   </li>
   <li id="LoginBTN">
     <a href="#">Log in<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void BTNLogIn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SqlMyName SqlUser= new SqlMyName ();
    DataSet DsUser = new DataSet();
    string StUser = "SELECT TblUsers.User_Name, TblUsers.Pass FROM TblUsers WHERE (((TblUsers.User_Name)= '" + TXTUserName.Text + "') AND ((TblUsers.Pass)= '" + TXTPass.Text + "'));";
    DsUser = SqlUser.chkData(StUser);
    if (DsUser.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string StShowFname = "SELECT TblUsers.Fname FROM TblUsers WHERE (((TblUsers.User_Name)= '" + TXTUserName.Text + "'));"; 
        DataSet DsShowFname = SqlUser.chkData(StShowFname);

        //How can I unshow or change text of <li>?
     } 
}
```

What should I do in the code behind?

Comment: Yes, you can. That answers your question, right? So what's your real question? Have you done any research to see how one can tell if the user is logged in from a code behind, or how one can interact with the DOM from code behind?

Comment: @mason My question is how can I do it with the code behind. I know how to check if the user loged in, but then what do I do? How do I change the text or making one of the <li> disapper?

Comment: Please edit the question so that it shows the actual question being asked and show how you are checking to make sure if a user is logged in with code behind. This makes your question clear and isolates the specific part that you want to learn about. While your at it, fix the title: there's no such thing as "bootsrap" and your title should accurately reflect your issue, not just state what technology you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of glaring issues with your code.

Let's start with security, because that should always be your number 1 priority. You are storing passwords in plaintext in your server. Any attacker that gains access to your server now how easy access to log in with these user accounts. And since users often use the same username and password on my sites, you've really done your users a huge disservice. Never store passwords in plaintext in your database. Instead, you should one way hash and salt the passwords. This means an attacker will have difficulty retrieving the actual passwords. To make sure a user's credentials are valid, you can apply the same hashing to their provided password and compare it to the hashed value. If they match, the user has the right password and you can allow them to login.

Secondly, users can easily perform SQL Injection attacks against your database, allowing them to steal and/or manipulate data. You need to use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509169/parameterized-queries-vs-sql-injection).

Your identifier names do not match standard .NET naming conventions. When you share code with others, such as on Stack Overflow, this becomes glaringly obvious and makes your code harder to read. Use PascalCase for function names. Use camelCase for local variables. Do not use abbreviations.

To show or hide server side controls, you can use the `.Visible` property. To make controls "server side" you can add the `runat="server"` attribute to their markup. Setting the `Visible` property to false will cause the HTML to not be rendered for that control and thus the client will not see it.

Markup

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li runat="server" id="RegisterButton">
    <a href="#">Register<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"</span></a>
   </li>
   <li id="LoginBTN" runat="server">
     <a href="#">Log in<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Code behind:

```
RegisterButton.Visible = false;
LoginBTN.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is working. About the security, it's a scholl project, so it doesn't that metter, thank you anyway.

Comment: @harel486 Yes, it absolutely does matter. If you don't learn actual security now, when are you planning to learn it?

Comment: @mason Has a good point. From my experience, I was never actually taught the importance of parameterizing in school. If you can pick up on good tips outside of school it will save you a lot of hassle trying to relearn things later.

Definitely a top quality answer as well. Most people don't take the time to explain all of that.

Answer (score -1):

I did this
**.aspx**

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li>
                    <p class="navbar-text">
                        <% =login %><li><% =logout %></li>
                    </p>
                </li>
     </ul>
```

**.cs**

```
if (userLogintatus == true)
        {
 login = string.Format("Welcome " + (string)Session["Name"])
            logout = "<a  href='../Account/Logout.aspx' style='color: red;'>Logout</a>";

        }
else logout = "";
```