# query using value from request gives no result while it should

Tags: c#, sql, .net, json, request

I have a javascript file that will send a value to a json file that has c# in there and sql queries to retrieve from the database.

I already ensured that the value has been retrieved, but my query doesn't give any result while it should.

JS:

```
$.postJSON('/path/path/html.aspx', {
            action: 'myAction', id: $(this).val(), sectiontext: chosensection
        }, function (j) {

          //some func

        });

    });
```

this above code in JS that will send values to html.aspx, values are sent im sure. But, when I use it in the query as request["chosensection"] it gives no result

and when i use a string that has the same value as request["sectiontext"] gives result.

Comment: What if you try a "chosentext" of `'; DROP TABLE STUDENTS; -- `? **Please please please** parameterize your SQL queries if you don't want to be a victim of SQL injections such as the above.

Comment: please explain, why would i drop the table?

Comment: Why wouldn't a malicious user?

Comment: is there anything wrong in my question syntax?

Comment: Do you understand the point I'm making? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509169/parameterized-queries-vs-sql-injection)

Comment: John is highlighting that your code is vulnerable to Sql injection attack.

Comment: No, honestly...

Comment: @Richard Well, I tried...

Comment: @Yura your question is now worse off for that edit.

Comment: @Yura, Why you removed the code ? please provide more code  more than that queries...

Comment: thanks i edited it. Now help me with this issue lol

Comment: The problem was with your posted code, not the fact that you included it in the question.

Comment: @john omg the issue is just in that part, the query part why would i need to provide code

Comment: Because an [mcve] is expected. You didn't have one before, but now your question is even worse because you don't even have any code in it. I wouldn't be surprised if the way your building your SQL query is the source of your problem, either.

Comment: You need to provide the code so people can help you. How can they help you if they can't see what you're doing?

Comment: @Richard ideally OP would post the full code that they're using to make the query, since the query looked fine aside from being constructed in a way that leaves OP open to SQL injection.

Comment: EDITED. how is it now?

Comment: I note in your javascript that your variable name is "sectiontext", but in C# it's "chosensection".

Comment: sorry it's actually sectiontext. Edited

Comment: Are you sure? Because the code you originally posted (before you removed it) had it as `chosentext`? (And you still left another copy of it to fix in the question)

Comment: yes i'm sure 100%

Comment: i even stored the request's value in a string and made sure it's correct so why it's not retrieveing from database

Comment: Just to be clear, your original post had `LIKE '%" + Request[chosentext] + "%'` not `sectiontext` or `chosensection`.  Clearly, `chosentext` is a variable, so could have any value - you haven't shown us what value. Put a breakpoint in your code after the string is constructed. I guarantee that either the query is different, or it's not looking at the database that you thought.

Comment: @Yura Given how you're generating your SQL, can you use the debugger to extract the completed SQL query that results from your request?

Comment: the thing wrong was that the string sent had some white space at the end that's why the query doesn't retrieve anything i had to remove the last char which is white space. chosentext = chosentext .Remove(chosentext .Length - 1);