# Else statement fails to work within a while loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysqldatareader

Below is my code to connect to the database using MySqlDataReader. Now the if statement is working fine but the else statement doesnt. When i use the debug function in VS it kept skipping the else statement and jump to the reader.Close();.
Any idea. Thanks

```
private void db()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(constr);
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user Where user_id ='" + Userid.Text + "'" + "And password='" + Password.Text + "'";

    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
        {
            Label1.Text = reader["user_id"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "nodata";
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to put `reader.Close()` inside the loop? If so, why is there a loop?

Comment: no, im starting to learn asp.net, there's an error msg : 'Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()' , so i add the while loop

Comment: You don't need a loop for that, just use `if (reader.Read())`

Comment: Move the `reader.Close()` outside of the loop, change it to `if (reader.Read())`, clean, rebuild, let us know if you're still seeing an issue.

Comment: This code doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You don't close a reader and then attempt to read from it!  Also your code has a massive security defect; read up on SQL injection.

Comment: Also as a side note to save you massive headaches (and easily found security vulnerabilities) in future, switch to using [parameterized SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509169/parameterized-queries-vs-sql-injection). At the moment I could use the username `' or 1 = 1; drop table user; -- ` and I'd have deleted your entire user table.

Comment: @Eric Lippert just starting to learn asp.net, any gd advice?

Comment: @john, consider writing a proper answer

Comment: @Rodrigo But they don't answer the question... they're just pointers on other problems with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Don't use string concatenation for building queries, but use parameterized queries!

As for your problem: I assume this query will only return either 1 or 0 rows, so you don't need the loop but just check

```
if (reader.Read()) {
    //...
}
```

Using `SELECT *` with column indexes is potentially dangerous, because you may not know what the "first" column returned is. I would suggest name your desired columns in the query

```
SELECT user_id, user_name ... FROM ...
```

What is the value of the first column returned? I assume, it's the `user_id`. Thus, this can never fulfill the condition `IsDBNull(0)` because `user_id` is your matching criterion in the `WHERE` clause. If your `WHERE` clause does not match any record in the table, `reader.Read()` will already fail, so you'll never get to your else branch.

Furthermore, I would suggest a `using` clause, which will dispose the reader automatically, so you don't have to care about closing it.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT user_id, foo, bar from user where user_id = @userid and password = @password";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", UserId.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Passowrd.Text);

using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    if (reader.Read()) {
        Label1.Text = reader["user_id"].ToString();
    } else {
        Label1.Text  ="nodata";
    }
}
```