# Convert string to a List type

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I have a List method where I need to return my enum values as a list type. The **Status** datatype is an enum object.

Here is my code:

```
public List<string> Statusstring
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (Status stat in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)).Cast<Status>().ToList())
            {
                status = stat;
            }

            return new List<string> { status.ToString() };
        }

    }
```

Here is my enum value:

```
public enum Status
{
    Enable,
    Disable
}
```

This is the error message I am getting:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<*char*>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<*string*>'

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: You're method signature indicates that you will return `List<string>`, but `.ToList()` of a string returns `List<char>`. The message actually explains this. I'm guessing that perhaps this still isn't want you want to do but only you know what you do want to do. Also, you're open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509169/parameterized-queries-vs-sql-injection).

Comment: yes @John how to make it to return string rather than char? I am been trying alot of methods but it didnt worked for me.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You have a `while` loop but you return on the first entry. You also may have another error about not returning a value since `reader.Read` may return false on the first call and not go inside the loop.

Comment: You mean convert each `char` to a string and return it as a list? `Status.Disable.ToString().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList()`, but I expect this isn't what you want. I don't know what you _do_ want, of course. [Example](http://rextester.com/KKO65267)

Comment: @RonBeyer i agree with that. I will modify my code. thank for letting me know

Comment: @John actually what i wanted is I need to print either the string Enable or Disable on to my combobox. Based on ur example this prints as a char value

Comment: a) Why are you using a combobox for a single value? b) Prateek's answer will enable you to return a list from a single value.

Comment: @John exactly, that what I wanted

Comment: can you please show how the enum value looks like

Comment: @Saif pls look into my question again tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in construct for this in .NET:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Statuses => Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status))
```

If you return `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a list you can assign this to arrays or lists. And the `Enum.GetNames(...)` returns as a `string[]`.

The documentation for this method is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Enum_GetNames_System_Type_)

Comment: @EmrahSüngü nice I just saw your answer. Great minds.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to return List only - Then below is a #hack

```
                if (reader["PRODUCTION_LINE_CODE"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    return new List<string> { Status.Enable.ToString() };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new List<string> {Status.Disable.ToString() };
                }
```

Update:- After discussion with OP

```
if (reader["PRODUCTION_LINE_CODE"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    return new List<string> { Status.Enable.ToString(), Status.Disable.ToString() };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new List<string> {Status.Disable.ToString() };
                }
```

Comment: With this code its printing the value I wanted but how about the return statement in the while loop?

Comment: @anonymous_apple Since you're only expecting a single value, use `SELECT TOP 1` in your query, and change `while` to and `if` statement. You will also need to return a value (e.g. empty list) from the method if no value is matched (e.g. `return new List<string>();`)

Comment: @anonymous_apple - if you can share some details about what Type the reader and db objects are - may be I can find something for it. On a side note while (reader.read()) is used generally when you expect several results after the query. Why not just do var result = reader.read(); check if result is false (i.e. nothing read) otherwise you already have this If conditions

Comment: But in my combobox I want to display both Enable and Disable options, to allow the user to select

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava can you open the chat window? it will be easier for me to discuss there.

Comment: ACtually now I want to return the whole enum list both Enable and Disable on my combobox itemsource

Comment: @anonymous_apple - Sure (trying to find where Chat window is) - I guess what you aret rying to do is that is the DB records says this is PRODUCTION_LINE_CODE then you want two items in the combobox (Enable & Disable)

Comment: @anonymous_apple - chat.stackoverflow.com ?? that's blocked at my workplace... bad luck

Answer (score 1):

What I see are a pretty much very convoluted solutions to a simple problem.

```
private static List<string> StatusString() => Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status)).ToList();
```

But since Enum values are not going to change during run time I would go for static member

You can define a static member→

```
private static List<string> StatusString = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status)).ToList();
```

Comment: @anonymous_apple look at my answer as well and you can make your method a little more generic so that you can save it to an array or a list.

Answer (score 0):

The property is named as `Statustring` but it is a `List<string>`?
I guess the codes below might be the proper implementation:

```
public string Statusstring
{
    get
    {
        string query;

        query = "Select PRODUCTION_LINE_CODE from productionlineconfig where ID = '" + ProductionLineConfigs.ProductionLineId + "'";

        reader = db.QueryCommand(query);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader["PRODUCTION_LINE_CODE"].ToString() == "1")
            {
                return Status.Enable.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return Status.Disable.ToString();
            }
        }
}
```

Or, if you have to return a `List<string>` you can try this

```
public List<string> Statusstring
{
    get
    {
        string query;

        query = "Select PRODUCTION_LINE_CODE from productionlineconfig where ID = '" + ProductionLineConfigs.ProductionLineId + "'";

        reader = db.QueryCommand(query);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader["PRODUCTION_LINE_CODE"].ToString() == "1")
            {
                return new List<string>().Add(Status.Enable.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<string>().Add(Status.Disable.ToString());
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First `enum` to list

```
var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status))
        .Cast<int>()
        .Select(x => x.ToString())
        .ToList();
```

then cast `enumList` to list of string

```
var stringList  = enumList.OfType<string>();
return stringList;
```

Comment: how about the return statement? how can i return the stringlist?

Answer (score 0):

This should do.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status))
            .Cast<Status>()
            .Select(x => x.ToString())
            .ToList();

        list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}

public enum Status
{
    Enable,
    Disable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)).Cast<Status>()
```

will return an Ienumerable.

```
 Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)).Cast<Status>().ToList();
```